# How to display an HTML canvas in a C# application?

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I wrote, using Chart.js, a script that takes in arguments data in a .txt file and returns a very sweet horizontal Bar chart in an HTML canvas. This chart automatically resizes depending on the length of the data and have very sweets animations that I want to keep.

But here is my problem: I have to display this chart in a C sharp application (I just started to learn about C sharp programming) and I wish I could keep all those great animations and not just save the canvas as an image.

I currently don't know if it is even possible and I haven't found very much about interactions between HTML and C sharp. Does someone know if it's possible? If it is what library/module/... should I use ?

Comment: If you can do it in HTML you can just output that HTML from your server side code. c# is not a web technology, to render C# you need to use MVC or webforms. Either way just put your HTML into the output. I'd say you probably need to learn more about how your web technology (whatever it is) works as there is large gaps in your question

Comment: What kind of "C# application" do you want to build (sorry, there are quite a few different kinds)? If it's a winform application, you might get somewhere with the [System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser) control. And I guess, WPF has something similar.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your comments. Maybe I asked this question too early. I haven't built this C# application myself and I will ask those who did it more documentation about it (and I will also learn more about C#).